# git - finding from what commit branch created

Tags: git, dvcs, git-commit, git-log

Suppose I had a branch 'develop' and I created a branch 'test_branch' from it. 
Then the both branches moved forward with lots of commits and even merges to each other.

Now, my commit graph turned into mess. So how to track the commit point from where my test_branch was created from develop branch.

Comment: Git does not record this information (and for that matter, you can delete the branch name and re-create it at the same, or some other, point later).  However, git *does* keep "reflogs" telling where branches pointed in the past, for up to 90 days by default, so if you only need to look back a few months, the information may be in the reflog.

Comment: thank you ... may be it will be helpful

Comment: Are there other branch forks and merges in these two branches? That is are the other branches in your projects which were merged with `development` branch or before `development` was created?

Comment: yes the develop branch has continuous updates from other branches

Comment: try git branch -av, and it will show the list of branch along with HEAD of each. By seeing itself, you will be able to know from which new branch has been created. If you like this approach, do respond me, i will write proper answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

try to search in the reflog

```
git reflog --date=local --all | grep branch
```

example output :

```
819b4c4 refs/heads/addMongoDB@{Wed Aug 20 13:59:24 2014}: branch: Created from origin/addMongoDB
cb6e2b4 refs/heads/workingServer@{Sun Aug 17 20:46:17 2014}: branch: Created from HEAD
```